# Binary search in 2D array using custorm Comparator

Tags: java, arrays, binary-search, comparator

I have a 2D integer array `[n][3]` and a target value.
I sort the array using

```
Arrays.sort(arr, (a,b)->Integer.compare(a[1],b[1]));
```

How can I use `Arrays.binarySearch` and a custom **comparator** to search arr along index `1` for a target value?  Something that could replace the following:

```
   int binSearch(int[][] arr, int target) {
      int low=0, high=arr.length-1;
      while( low < high ) {
         int mid=(low+high)/2;
         if( arr[mid][1] == target ) {
            return i;
         }    
         else if( arr[mid][1] < target {
            low=mid+1;
         }
         else {
            high=mid-1;
         }
      }
      return -(low+1);
   }
```

**EDIT:** Arrays.sort works how I need it to - my initial array for example {{1,3,5},{7,1,6},{4,2,1}} sorts on the middle value to {{7,1,6},{4,2,1},{1,3,5}}

I thought I could write a similar expression for Arrays.binarySearch where each element (1x3) of the array is compared to a target integer.  Something like:

```
int idx = Arrays.binarySearch(arr, target, (a,b)->Integer.compare(a[1],b));
```

I can't really use the same comparator as in the sort because they are different types - the search array is an array of `1x3` sized elements and my target is a single integer.  I need to do a binary search.

Answer (score 2):

Static method [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(T%5B%5D,T,java.util.Comparator)) has the following declaration:

```
public static <T> int binarySearch(T[] a, T key, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

Where `T` is the type of the elements in the array. In this case, it happens to be `int[]`.

The important distinction between your method `binSearch()` and `Arrays.binarySearch()` is that your method expects an `int` argument `target`, meanwhile you need to pass `int[]` into `binarySearch()`.

Since the required *comparator* needs only the second element (*i.e. at index* `1`) of the array, the other elements of the `key` can have any value. Therefore, an array of two elements, like that

```
new int[]{0, target} // the first value, is arbitrary
```

will be a sufficient in order to utilize the built-in `binarySearch()`.

```
int index = Arrays.binarySearch(source, new int[]{0, i}, comparator);
```

To define a *comparator*, you might make use of static methods `comparing()` and `comparingInt()` of the `Comparator` interface introduced with Java 8.

With that, the code bowls down to a couple of lines, and might be written like that:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] source = {{1, 3, 5}, {7, 1, 6}, {4, 2, 1}};
    
    Comparator<int[]> bySecondElement = Comparator.comparingInt(arr -> arr[1]);
    
    Arrays.sort(source, bySecondElement);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { // searching for arrays having a value of i as second element
        int index = Arrays.binarySearch(source, new int[]{0, i}, bySecondElement);
        System.out.printf("target: %d\tindex: %d\n", i, index);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
target: 0   index: -1   // no such element
target: 1   index: 0    // {7, 1, 6}
target: 2   index: 1    // {4, 2, 1}
target: 3   index: 2    // {1, 3, 5}
```

Comment: This is actually a pretty good solution. The array used as a key could even contain only the target var repeated twice just for clarity, but since the second element is the only one confronted by the comparator the first array's element could be anything. This is great!

Comment: Thanks, @Dan, if solution already exists in the JDK no need to reinvent it, because it's always well-tested, performant and reliable.